# VideoJS HLS stream won't resume after pause

Tags: video.js, playback, http-live-streaming

When I play my HLS video stream with Video.JS and I pause it, the stream won't play after I resume. I found this solution:

```
player.on("pause", function () {
player.one("play", function () {
  player.load();
  player.play();
});
```

});

This isn't working anymore on version 5.8.8. Is there another solution?

The error I get is:

Failed to read the 'buffered' property from 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.